# Is it better to use a JSON configuration file that loads at the beginning of App or using classes that has static/final variables in Flutter?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, memory-efficient

I'm creating an app using Flutter that has around 1500+ predefined colors and gradients. 
I was wondering should I create a configuration file that always loads at the beginning of the app or should I create a class that has static final/const variables such as map+list?

Which one would be more memory efficient, less error prone and code friendly? 
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would assume that hardcoded values are stored more efficiently than some runtime JSON operation, but I am not even sure if you should really load all of the predefined assets at once, i.e. maybe lazy loading should be preferred.

Comment: Why json files and not static const map that loads at the beginning of the app ??

Comment: If your app is using online in future, using json file is better way to update but if it not, using constant variables is much more convenient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments. Now since I don’t need to do update OTA, I decided to create a class with static map+list combination

I found the benefits are:
1. Less error prone because the naming will be checked by editor. 
2. Only loaded in pages where we need it. 
3. Compared to reading from a JSON files, it doesn’t need async functions to get the data thus faster. Because File reading is an I/O operation